# How to map hdr file image onto cubemap with Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

Curently based on [Sascha Willems](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/texturecubemap/texturecubemap.cpp#L128) examples I've cerated `samplerCube` texture for fragment shader. 
It has same JPG image copied to all 6 layers (faces).

I use stbi image library for image loading, it works okay if I use it for regular 2D texture, but if it's mapped on cube mesh it creates distorted image:

```cpp
        int width = 0, height = 0, channel = 0;
        float* pixels = stbi_loadf("textures/test.hdr", &width, &height, &channel, STBI_rgb_alpha);
        if(!pixels) throw std::runtime_error("failed to load texture image!");

        this->texture_image.create_image(width, height, VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT);
        this->texture_image.fill_memory(width, height, 4*sizeof(float), pixels);
        this->texture_image.create_image_view(VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT, VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT);

        stbi_image_free(pixels);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found how to do it here: https://learnopengl.com/PBR/IBL/Diffuse-irradiance
Even if it's in OpenGL the concenpt is the same.